# Do member variables have external linkage?

Tags: c++

I have read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage) and it says that

> names of classes, their member functions, static data members (const
>   or not), nested classes and enumerations, and functions first
>   introduced with friend declarations inside class bodies

have external linkage by default.. But what about the variables declared inside the class body that are not specified static? Also, it starts out with

> Any of the following names declared at namespace scope have external
>   linkage

, but is class scope considered a namespace scope? I mean class scope and namespace scope are different, so why do they start out by saying that the following is applicable for the mentioned declared inside a namespace scope? I mean, for example, member functions are declared in class scope and they mention them as if it was namespace scope?

Comment: Variables never have linkage. Only *names* have linkage. (Because linkage describes how two like names relate to one another.)

Comment: @KerrekSB well, then I think that I meant names rather than variables.. More specifically, "names of member variables"

Comment: Member variables are used to refer to objects inside the class. They don't require "linkage". Their names translates into offsets into instances of the class.

Comment: Class methods do have linkage. The class name is a scope, but is not a namespace.

Comment: @jxh ahh okay.. But why do class functions have linkage? Can't they also just translate to an offset?

Comment: Class methods have linkage because you need to be able to call a function when you invoke a method. The method may be defined in some other translation unit or library, so linkage is required to find the actual function that represents the method. When you refer to a member variable, the class declaration must be in view (otherwise the class would be an incomplete type), so the offset is known to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following example:

```
class C
{
public:
    int n;
};

C e;
namespace { C i; }
```

`e` has external linkage, `i` internal. How much sense would it make to speak of linkage of `n` now? If at all, you could consider `n` inheriting the linkage of the containing object, thus `e.n` would have external, `i.n` internal linkage – for better understanding only, I do not consider this as correct wording...

Comment: Okay, we are getting there.. But what about the name ´C´? Does that have external linkage and thus ´n´ too? What about member functions - are they also just offsets?

Comment: @overso As your cited article says, the name C has external linkage unless defined in anonymous namespace. n standing alone cannot be referred to independently (without the sourrounding object). So it does not make much sense to speak of linkage in this case. Member functions are different, though: Although you only can call them on objects, they still exist only once per class and exist even without any instance of a class being created. This gets obvious looking at the fact that you can assign a member function to an appropriate member function pointer without any object instance involved!

Comment: Oh thank you!! But so the class name has external linkage unless defined in anonymous namespace.. But does this also apply for member functions? And this they will always be declared at the same place as the class name, does it mean that the member function name will always have the same linkage as the class name? Also, cppreference mentions class names and member function names like if member functions could be declared somewhere else than the class name..

Comment: Well, sure it applies for member functions, too: *"names of classes, their member functions, [...]"* classes and member functions are treated alike... Then in the introduction: *"unless the namespace is unnamed or is contained within an unnamed namespace"* Think of: if the class is defined inside an anonymous namespace, the member functions are as well (or did you ever manage to declare a member function outside the class???). Luckily (in this case), we have no extension functions as in C#, that would complicate the matter a lot...

Comment: In other words: member functions of a class always have the same linkage as the class itself...

Comment: Okay great! But since member functions cannot be declared outside the class scope, isn't it¨ sort of redundant to also mention "their member functions" when stating what has external linkage by default when declared at namespace scope, if they already did mention class names?

Comment: @overso 3.5 \[basic.link] p5: "a member function, static data member, a named class or enumeration of class scope, or an
unnamed class or enumeration defined in a class-scope typedef declaration such that the class or enumeration
has the typedef name for linkage purposes (7.1.3), has the same linkage, if any, as the name of the class of
which it is a member".

Comment: @overso Well, member functions having less restrictive linkage than the classes themselves does not make sense. That would ressemble kind of "you are allowed to release the handbreake, but you are not allowed to enter my car"... The other way round *could* make sense, e. g. private functions *could* have internal linkage even if the class had external one (but they do *not*!). So there is no redundancy in specifying *all* functions having same linkage as the class...

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the standard:

> A name is said to have linkage when it might denote the same object, reference, function, type, template, namespace or value as a name introduced by a declaration in another scope

Translation to plain English:

*If you can redeclare it in another scope, it has linkage. Otherwise, nope.*

You cannot redeclare a non-static class data member in another scope, so it has no linkage.